# Please explain usage for for/f command?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am using the following to output the java version which I grabbed from another site:

```
java -version 2> java.txt
for /f "tokens=3" %%x in ('find /i "java version" java.txt')
```

Output is:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is the full code:

```
@echo off

set JavaTemp=C:\Windows\Gpologs

java -version
if "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" ( goto VersionCheck ) ELSE ( goto Install )

:VersionCheck
java -version 2> %JavaTemp%\java.txt
for /f "tokens=3" %%x in ('find /i "java version" %JavaTemp%\java.txt') do (
  if %%~x==1.7.0_45 goto :eof
  if %%~x==1.7.0_40 goto Install
  if %%~x==1.7.0_25 goto Install
  if %%~x==1.7.0_21 goto Install
  if %%~x==1.7.0_17 goto Install
  if %%~x==1.7.0_15 goto Install
)

:Install
msiexec /i "\\servershare\sharename\Java\jre1.7.0_45_x86\jre1.7.0_45.msi" /qn
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
    >>"\\servershare\sharename\jre_1.7.45.x64.csv" echo "%computername%","%date%","%Time%","%ErrorLevel%","Java Runtime 1.7.0_45x86 Installed"
    >>"%windir%\GpoLogs\jre_1.7.45.x64.txt" echo "Java Runtime 1.7.0_45x86 Installed"
) else (
    >>"\\servershare\sharename\JavaInstallErrors.csv" echo "%computername%","%date%","%Time%","%ErrorLevel%","Error trying to install Java 1.7_45x86"
)
```

I just need to know why the tokens is 3? please explain as soon as I get my head around it, it will make a lot more sense :)

Comment: Your code is incomplete - you have no DO clause. Please edit the question to include full functioning code. Also, I presume your "Output" is the output of the `java -version` command, not the output of the FOR statement. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi not sure how I can add the code, not seeing any option to add :/

Comment: There is an edit link at the bottom of your question, below the tags. You should not blindly post a large batch script. You should post the minimal code that clearly demonstrates the problem. But you did not post enough. It is not clear what you are attempting to do, as the posted FOR command is incomplete. The output you show could not have come from the code you posted, so it is difficult to understand what the output represents.

Comment: Sorry about this, I have updated the full code set, originally I wanted to know how it delimits the code which Foxidrive has answered. You mention that the DO clause is not valid, is this still the case with the full code attached ?

Comment: Better :)  I edited your question to properly format your code. I suggest you go through the motions of editing your question so that you can see the changes I made (no need to actually change anything). This should help you in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foxidrive answered your question.

Unrelated to your question, your code can be greatly simplified with the exact same result:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%V in (
  'java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find /i "java version"'
) do if %%~V==1.7.0_45 exit /b
msiexec /i "\\servershare\sharename\Java\jre1.7.0_45_x86\jre1.7.0_45.msi" /qn
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
  >>"\\servershare\sharename\jre_1.7.45.x64.csv" echo "%computername%","%date%","%Time%","%ErrorLevel%","Java Runtime 1.7.0_45x86 Installed"
  >>"%windir%\GpoLogs\jre_1.7.45.x64.txt" echo "Java Runtime 1.7.0_45x86 Installed"
) else (
  >>"\\servershare\sharename\JavaInstallErrors.csv" echo "%computername%","%date%","%Time%","%ErrorLevel%","Error trying to install Java 1.7_45x86"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The default delimiters are space and TAB

You count the 'words' in the string and use spaces/tabs as separators, and your 3rd token/word is `"1.7.0_25"`

Comment: +1 and for reference here are some great sites to bookmark for understanding batch: [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx), [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/), [Rob Van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php), [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/), and [ComputerHope](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php/board,2.0.html)